# ClassNotFoundException - com.google.android.gms.chimera.GmsModuleInitializer

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

This exception raise after added Google MapView feature, after launch the app, Exception throws immediately, however app is not crash, don't have idea what causing it.

> 03-07 03:17:42.514 2146-2146/com.google.android.gms E/ChimeraModuleLdr: Initialization failed for module com.google.android.play.games
>                                                                           java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.chimera.GmsModuleInitializer" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/system/app/PlayGames.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
>                                                                               at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
>                                                                               at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
>                                                                               at bxd.loadClass(:com.google.android.gms:34)
>                                                                               at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
>                                                                               at com.google.android.gms.chimera.container.GmsModuleApi.onApkLoaded(:com.google.android.gms:91)
>                                                                               at bxh.a(:com.google.android.gms:146)
>                                                                               at com.google.android.chimera.container.ConfigurationManager.a(:com.google.android.gms:655)
>                                                                               at com.google.android.chimera.container.ConfigurationManager.a(:com.google.android.gms:485)
>                                                                               at bvh.a(:com.google.android.gms:1106)
>                                                                               at bvh.onReceive(:com.google.android.gms:229)
>                                                                               at hjw.onReceive(:com.google.android.gms:62)
>                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2419)
>                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1700(ActivityThread.java:135)
>                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1272)
>                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
>                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
>                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
>                                                                               at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>                                                                               Suppressed: java.io.IOException: unable to open DEX file
>                                                                               at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFileNative(Native Method)
>                                                                               at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFile(DexFile.java:296)
>                                                                               at dalvik.system.DexFile.(DexFile.java:80)
>                                                                               at dalvik.system.DexFile.(DexFile.java:59)
>                                                                               at dalvik.system.DexPathList.loadDexFile(DexPathList.java:263)
>                                                                               at dalvik.system.DexPathList.makeDexElements(DexPathList.java:230)
>                                                                               at dalvik.system.DexPathList.(DexPathList.java:112)
>                                                                               at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.(BaseDexClassLoader.java:48)
>                                                                               at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.(PathClassLoader.java:65)
>                                                                               at bxd.(:com.google.android.gms:16)
>                                                                               at bwi.a(:com.google.android.gms:89)
>                                                                               at bxh.a(:com.google.android.gms:124)
>                                                                                       ... 16 more

My gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    // Skip some version control stuffs
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.hoelee.obriensdelivery"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode code
        versionName nameFull
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    lintOptions {
        disable "ResourceType"
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.2.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.5.1'
    compile 'com.hrules:horizontalnumberpicker:1.1.1'
    compile 'com.baoyz.pullrefreshlayout:library:1.2.0'
    compile 'com.github.clans:fab:1.6.4'
    compile 'com.sdsmdg.tastytoast:tastytoast:0.1.1'
    compile 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.0.1'
    compile 'ch.acra:acra:4.9.0'
    compile ('com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.2.0'){
        exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-ads'
    }
    compile ('com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:10.2.0'){
        exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-ads'
    }
}
```

I don't call GmsModuleInitializer Class, it is some dependency use it? 
This app is not games, should I add Google Play mobile services?
Thanks.

Comment: has your mapview works?

Comment: Yes, MapView tested no issue so far.

Comment: Then ignore this warning

Comment: This is Exception, not warning.

Comment: You are using rooted device. am i right?

Comment: Yes, but I tested in tablet and simulator that produce same Exception, I'm sure not related to rooted devices.